# Datasheetview copy managedmetadata field

Tags: 2010, list, development, managed-metadata, datasheet

We have a list with 2 metadatafields, however in this list the user wants to use datasheetview to copy many rows, the problem is when you try top copy it says managed metadatafields are readonly, is there any workaround for this?

We just want to be able to copy rows as easy as possible

Comment: Jen.... Did the Workflow really copy those metadata columns after adding the action ***"Set field in current item"*** using workflow method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the metadata columns from the datasheet view. Since metadata columns are populated through Term Store or Enterprise Keywords , these values are only modified at the Term Store Administration level by Contributors or Group Managers.

A list level user even though can update other list columns , but metadata columns are special columns whose data can be updated only if the user also has the rights to create tags or keywords at the Term Store level.

Comment: I cant remove the metadata columns they want easy copy.  So my second solution was to replace the managed metadata columns for lookup columns from lists, instead of a term store

Comment: You need not remove metadata columns from list. Just do not include them in the datasheet view to facilitate easy copying.

Answer (score 1):

I created a workflow that started on change to accomplish this.

1. Navigate to your library. Open edit properties for one of your items and add a managed metadata value. Save.
2. View the list/library in datasheet view to get the managed metadata "code" - will look something like 1;#ManagedMetadataValue. Copy this value EXACTLY how it appears.
3. Create a workflow for this list/library in SharePoint designer that starts on item change.
4. Add the workflow action - Set field in current item.
5. For field, select your managed metadata column. For value, paste your managed metadata code you copied from your datasheet view.
6. Publish your workflow and mass change your items.
7. Workflow should run and add all your managed metadata.